# FOpen fails (stream != nullPtr) when folder is open

Tags: c++

Pretty new to C++ and debugging someone else's code (unfortunately).

He's writing data out to a file that's coming in, and then re-reading it later.

```
fptmp = fopen ("c:\\tmp\\tf00.clay", "w" );
```

This is really the only line of code that matters, as I get a `debug assertion failed (stream != nullPtr)` when trying to write to this file when I have that folder open in Windows Explorer.

I searched stackoverflow/elsewhere but nothing came up.  Is anyone familiar with this issue?  Any way around it, other than trying to force close the folder?

Comment: fptmp = null? maybe no rights to create the file at location? get the error code after using fopen.

Comment: fptmp is definitely null, but it creates the file fine if windows explorer is closed... Perhaps it's situational and the file isn't getting properly deleted the time before causing a rights error?

Comment: as i said, get the error code when fptmp = null... The error codes are there to help you debug stuff

Comment: this is a third party dll -- I can't debug direct/alter the file easily

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I read that question already, and it didn't apply to my situation.

Comment: Did you try figuring out which process exactly is locking a file or folder in Windows? https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: it's just this process accessing this temporary file, no other processes interact with it.  I could do that check, but i think i'm going to find it's my own process.

Comment: For some reason, a secure version of `fopen` works in Windows more recent compilers, `fopen_s`. Have you tried, `fopen_s(&fptmp, "c:\\tmp\\tf00.clay", "w")`?

Comment: When @Neijwiert says to get the error code, presumably he means to check the value of errno. If fopen fails then this should be set to something that gives a bit more information on the exact cause of the failure. If you can't change the code to output the value, because it's a third-party DLL, you should still be able to run it under a debugger to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.  I tried duplicating this issue as close as possible on a test app, and it works fine with windows explorer open.

I was able to try and change the code to output an error if it was showing up null, but the if check apparently didn't hit.

I still find it odd I can consistently get this from the DLL, but not in a test app... but for now i'll try fopen_s and hope for the best.

Comment: My only (last) guess would be that there's some compiler flags that are making this run unsafe for some reason

Comment: @SeanBurton yeah i did indeed mean something like that, but as OP didnt specify platform i couldnt really tell if errno was set or not. Maybe its undefined behaviour or maybe the dll gets unloaded prematurely (which still is undefined behaviour).